# Hooking functions in Linux and/or OSX?

Tags: disassembly, linux, dynamic-analysis, osx, symbols

I want to hook functions in a library (`lib.so` or `lib.dylib`) from another process. I know that unlike windows libraries, libraries in Linux and Mac still have their symbols (function names and parameters).

[API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) allows you hook exported functions from other libraries but only for windows, which is somewhat of what I need.

Basically I want to hook certain functions in either Linux or mac and see their parameters and order of calls.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That apimonitor software looks amazing. I did search apimonitor in google and came back with Valgrind

Answer (score 9):

You can simply export the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD` (on Linux) or `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` (on OS X) pointing to (the full path of) your library before running your target, like in this example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083337/overriding-malloc-using-the-ld-preload-mechanism

This is for hooking functions to do whatever you want (not to spy on function calls).

Answer (score 8):

Check the trace family:

- ltrace: a library tracer
- strace: a kernel call (syscall) tracer
- ptrace: a programmable tracer

and also:

- radare's [itrace](http://radare.org/y/?p=examples&f=itrace)

Answer (score 6):

For OS X, [dtrace](http://dtrace.org/blogs/about/) should do the trick. dtrace is supposed to exist for Linux as well, though I don’t know how well it is supported, and I believe there are other equivalent tools there.

Comment: i see examples of dtrace with system calls but none on other libraries. can dtrace be used for a game to see which functions are being called in a specific library (ex. engine.dylib) and perhaps its parameters as well.

Comment: Yes, the `pid` provider can do this: http://dtrace.org/guide/chapter30.html